# Google cloud dataflow job status

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I run dataflow jobs within a unix shell script, and need to know each job final/completion status, is there any command line tool to grab the job completion status?

Answer (score 4):

There's indeed a CLI to retrieve jobs execution status :

`gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=<PROJECT_ID> --filter="id=<JOB_ID>" --format="get(state)"`

Comment: adding on that for cloud run `get(state)` didn't work, `get(status)` did the trick. I.e. `gcloud beta run jobs describe helloworld1 --region=europe-west9 --format="get(status)"`. Thank a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Dataflow has a CLI that is available as part of gcloud.

You may need to install gcloud alpha components:

```
$ gcloud components update alpha
```

After that, you should be able to use `gcloud alpha dataflow jobs list` to list all the jobs in a project or `gcloud alpha dataflow jobs show <JOBID>` for more information on a specific job.

You can find more details about this command and others below at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/dataflow/jobs/list